# How to disable auto-indent when pasting in BusyBox's Vi?

Tags: indentation, busybox-vi

I have a Vi running as BusyBox executable (VMware ESXi):

```
$ vi --version
BusyBox v1.20.2 (2014-08-27 12:48:18 PDT) multi-call binary.
```

Is there a way to disable auto-indent when pasting the code? Neither of the methods described in [Turning off auto indent when pasting text into vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514445/turning-off-auto-indent-when-pasting-text-into-vim) works for Busybox.

I can `set noautoindent` before pasting and `set autoindent` after, but is there a persistent method?

Comment: You can use autocommands/mappings to set and unset based on your keys/clicks. Did you tried `:set paste` command before pasting ?

Comment: @SibiCoder, the question is about "BusyBox Vi", not "Vim".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by [the source](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/editors/vi.c), the only settable options in "BusyBox Vi" are:

```
autoindent
showmatch
ignorecase
```

So, the answer seems to be "no".

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about BusyBox, but avoiding indentations is effective with the `:se paste` command. I include in my `~/.vimrc` the definition:

```
map #P :se paste
```

so by doing `#P` I can turn indenting off. Useful when copying and pasting from
one terminal to another.

Comment: The 'paste' option doesn't exist.

Comment: @Antony It does in normal vim. Try `:set all` and all possible options are shown.

Comment: The OP isn't using vim.

Comment: @Antony Thanks, I realize now. Didn't know about BusyBox.

Comment: Aye, there are several variants of vi around, though Vim is the most popular.